# Widget items disappearing

Tags: theme-development, widgets

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        "name" => "Top Widget Area",
        "id" => "topWidgetArea-$i",
    ));
```

I just create a new sidebar with this.
I'm displaying this sidebar in my `header.php` like this:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( "Top Widget Area" ); ?>
```

It's displaying no problem and I can put every widget to my sidebar in wp-admin's Appearance → Widgets page. When I refresh this widgets page, all the widgets (which are in the Top Widget Area) are disappearing. I'll explain it with a video. Please check: http://screenr.com/szG8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing widget's ID from `topWidgetArea` to `top-widget-area` solved my problem. Widget ID must have hypen. I tried a lots of variations for ID (like `testtesttest`, `asdasdasd`, `widgetareaaa`) . I'm not sure, why .

Comment: No capitals are allowed either.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed capitals that is why it doesn't work.

Use a name like `this-dynamic-sidebar` or `this_dynamic_sidebar`. It should be the same name used when you registered the sidebar.

Comment: That is not exactly true. I have have used capital letters in my theming for sidebars and have had no problems. To me with this site it seems to me to be a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is the variable `$i` that is the issue, causing probably a php error because it is not defined.

Just had the same issue. Removing the `id` prams solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters for **register_sidebar**, from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar#Parameters:

> id - Sidebar id - Must be all in lowercase, with no spaces (default is a numeric auto-incremented ID).

**Hyphens and underscores are not required**. Just **no uppercase, no spaces**.